# Viewing the Size of BST

Tags: haskell

Assuming I have `data BSearch x y = None | Node x y (BSearch x y) (BSearch x y)` (which means that the tree is either empty or it's not) and I am trying to write the function, `bstSize :: BSearch x y -> Int` .

It basically runs like,

```
> bstSize None
0
> bstSize (Node 0 57 Empty (Node 0 65 Empty Empty))
2
```

I know how to define a tree with 1 node and one with 2 nodes, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement the pattern into actual code for nth number of nodes. The only thing I can think of is counting the number of right parentheses, counting the number of times "Nodes" occurs in the argument, or counting the number of times "Empty" occurs in the argument minus 1 and I am not really sure how to do any of those things. I understand that I might have to use recursion, but I'm not sure how I would go about that. Here is what I have so far:

```
data BSearch q w = None | Node q w (BSearch q w) (BSearch q w)
bstSize :: BSearch q w -> Int
bstSize Empty = 0
bstSize(Node a b None None) = 1
bstSize(Node a b None (Node a b None None))) = 2
bstSize(Node a b None (Node a b None (Node a b None None))))) = 3
```

Obviously, I'm not supposed to flat out define what 2, 3, 4, etc. look like, but I did it to see what the pattern looked like and to see what I could use. So far, I don't really understand what to do.

Comment: Looks like you're going to need some recursion...

Comment: Hint: you don't need to specify the whole skeleton of the tree; children of the current node can be bound by variables too. As in: `bstSize (Node a b l r) = ...`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use recursion:

```
Data BSearch q w = None | Node q w (BSearch q w) (BSearch q w)
bstSize :: BSearch q w -> Int
bstSize None = 0
bstSize(Node _ _ la lb) = 1 + bstSize la + bstSize lb
```

You made a small mistake with `Empty` to `None`.

Furthermore the size of a `Node` is one plus the size of the left child and the right child. You can do this using *recursion*. With recursion you call the same method on a different input (in this case the children of the node).

Since every tree is empty. Eventually all children will end.

**How does this work?**

Say you have value `Node a b None (Node a b None (Node a b None None))))`, then the function call

```
bstSize (Node a b None (Node a b None (Node a b None None))))) --1st call
```

will unify `la` with `None` and `lb` with `(Node a b None (Node a b None None)))`. Now the function calls `bstSize la` and `bstSize lb`. Since `la` is `None`, the first call will return `0`. For the second call it is more complicated.

The second call is:

```
bstSize Node a b None (Node a b None None))))  --2nd call
```

Now in **this** function call, `la` is unified with `None` thus the result is zero, and `lb` with `Node a b None None`. This leads to a third call:

```
bstSize (Node a b None None) --3rd call
```

Since both `la` and `lb` unify with `None`, their result is both `0`, thus the result is:

```
bstSize (Node a b None None) --3rd call
= 1 + bstSize None + bstSize None
= 1+0+0
= 1
```

The result returns to the second call:

```
bstSize Node a b None (Node a b None None)))) --2nd call
= 1 + bstSize None + bstSize (Node a b None None)))) 
= 1 + 0 + 1
= 2
```

And the final result is:

```
bstSize (Node a b None (Node a b None (Node a b None None))) --1st call
= 1 + bstSize None + bstSize (Node a b None (Node a b None None))
= 1 + 0 + 2
= 3
```

Recursion is a powerful concept but can easily lead to infinite loops. You better make sure you always do recursive calls with different elements than the given one, and that the call tree is finite.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way to cheat in any recent GHC. Don't bother trying this on a class assignment.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

module MyModuleNotYours
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

data BSearch x y = None
                 | Node x y (BSearch x y) (BSearch x y)
  deriving (F.Foldable, Functor)

bstSize :: BSearch x y -> Int
bstSize = F.sum . (1 <$)
```